Why does slices.BinarySearchFunc call the comparison function with the matched element twice?
I was curious about what was happening inside the comparison function passed to slices.BinarySearchFunc, so I added some diagnostic code and noticed that it printed the output for the matched element twice.
Here's an example showing the behavior:
package main

import (
    "cmp"
    "log"
    "slices"
    "testing"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

func init() {
    log.SetFlags(0)
}

func Test(t *testing.T) {
    numbers := []int{
        1, 2, 3,
    }
    timesCalled := 0
    comparisonFunc := func(l, r int) int {
        timesCalled++
        log.Printf("Comparing %d and %d", l, r)
        result := cmp.Compare(l, r)
        if result == 0 {
            log.Printf("Matched %d and %d", l, r)
        }
        return result
    }
    if idx, found := slices.BinarySearchFunc(numbers, 2, comparisonFunc); found {
        assert.Equal(t, 2, numbers[idx])
    } else {
        assert.Fail(t, "Number not found")
    }
    assert.LessOrEqual(t, timesCalled, 2)
}

Example output from the Go Playground:
=== RUN   Test
Comparing 2 and 2
Matched 2 and 2
Comparing 1 and 2
Comparing 2 and 2
Matched 2 and 2
    prog_test.go:35: 
            Error Trace:    /tmp/sandbox3165947586/prog_test.go:35
            Error:          "3" is not less than or equal to "2"
            Test:           Test
--- FAIL: Test (0.00s)
FAIL

Program exited.

Is this behavior expected, and is there a way to write the comparison function such that slices.BinarySearchFunc stops as soon as it finds a matching element?

It is called one more time to check if the element is actually found. If the searched value is not in the slice, the function returns the location it should be inserted along with false, which is the result of the comparison of the looked up value with the value at that location. When the value is not in the slice, the number of calls to compare func is optimal.
Something that is maybe missing in the documentation is that BinarySearch returns the occurrence of the value in the slice with the lowest index, so it does not return the first index it finds. Thus, it keeps searching even after it finds the target value.
Looking at the source code for BinarySearch. it also seems to handle the edge case where the following is the last thing that executes in the search loop:
        if cmp(x[h], target) < 0 {
            i = h + 1 // preserves cmp(x[i - 1], target) < 0
        } else {

cmp(x[i], target) would have been called in the previous iterations, and would be forgotten. So The function calls cmp(x[i],target) once more before returning.

Binary search returns 1, not 2. Also, why do you think it is a lame implementation? The implementation is correct if, for instance, the slice contained multiple '2' values.
